# GSON, custom deserializer for multiple classes

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2, json-deserialization

I need to implement a custom GSON deserializer (with Retrofit2) for my Android application in kotlin. This is how an example of how api gives me result:

example1:

```
 {
     "res": {
          "status": {
              "code": 0,
              "message": "some message",
          }
     },
     "somedata": {
         "someid" = "12345",
         "sometext" = "a text" 
     }
 }
```

example2:

```
{
     "res": {
          "status": {
              "code": 0,
              "message": "another message",
          }
     },
     "anotherdata": {
         "anotherid" = "54321",
         "anothertext" = "b text" 
     }
 }
```

this is relative kotlin classes for mapping data (i would use deserializer for extract data inside "res" object):

```
abstract class GenericResponse() {
    //abstract class for common fields
    constructor(status: Status?) : this()
}

class Status(
    val code: Int,
    val message: String
)
```

and this is specific response classes:

```
data class SomeData(
    val status: Status,
    val someid : String,
    val sometext : String
): GenericResponse(status)


data class AnotherData(
    val status: Status,
    val anotherid : String,
    val anothertext : String
): GenericResponse(status)
```

i've tryed to create a custom deserializer class  that implements JsonDeserializer, something like:

```
class CustomDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<GenericResponse> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement?,
        typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): GenericResponse {

    val rootElement = json!!.asJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("res")
    //further implementation, should return SomeData or AnotherData object
}
```

but it doesn't work. How can i do?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse both the response with one class?

Comment: Yes, i need a unique parser for both responses (this is an example, but in my real project i have more that two responses).

Comment: ` "anothertext" = "b text: ` is not a valid JSON

Comment: typing error, edited my post.

Comment: @ Check my updated answer

Answer (score -2):

For your JSON response

```
{
"res": {
    "status": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "some message"
    }
},
"somedata": {
    "someid": "12345",
    "sometext": "a text"
},
"anotherdata": {
    "anotherid": "54321",
    "anothertext": "b text"
}
}
```

The data model classes can be
Somedata

```
data class Somedata(
val someid: String,
val sometext: String
)
```

Status

```
data class Status(
val code: Int,
val message: String
)
```

Anotherdata

```
data class Anotherdata(
val anotherid: String,
val anothertext: String
)
```

These classes can be combined to parse the entire response
GenericResponse

```
data class GenericResponse(
val anotherdata: Anotherdata,
val res: Res,
val somedata: Somedata
)
```

In retrofit use like

```
@POST("url")
fun callingMethod(@Field("username") username: String, @Field("password") 
password: String): GenericResponse
```

Comment: i need ti keep separate classes, and i need the parser for do some data manupulation while parsing data. And my json example is about two differend api response

Comment: @giozh You can access the variables from the genericresponse, you don't need any parse libraries for that purpose

Comment: As i told in my previous comment, my code is a very simplified example. In my real app i must have a different object (so not a GenericResponse instance) for each api response, so i need a deserializer/parser too.

Comment: GenericResponse class is to hold the base response, you need to add seperate classes for other json reponses, and you should keep those objects inside your genericresponse class then only you can parse it.